# Manually sent ICMP redirect packets

Tags: linux, mac-osx, redirect, tcp, icmp

I'm trying to sent a ICMP redirect to my router to add a new route, as I can not configure it from the portal, and have no access to it though telnet/ssh.

The scenario is the next.
LAN network
192.168.1.0/24
New network
102.168.2.0/24

If I setup all the devices though DHCP or by hand I can access all the devices, but I prefer to add the route to the router to handle it.

I tried to found some info on the ping man and internet, with no luck

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That'll not work. ICMP redirects are not intended to serve the purpose you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use an ICMP message type that is meant for route optimisation between gateways, not host-based configuration changes.

ICMP Redirect messages are used to notify a remote host to send data packets on an alternative route.  Even if you can get a router to listen to your requests, how long the route lasts will vary and/or be seen as malicious activity by the network owner.